# How to get a PHP file to run with an ".html" extension?

Tags: php, html, apache

I have to execute PHP codes in a HTML file, but my server not doing it. I added a handler `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm` but still it's not responding to the code.

The code I tried to execute

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<body>  
<?php  
$url=basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);  
?>  
<p>the file name is <?php echo $url; ?></p> 
 </body> </html>
```

and the result is "the file name is"

[image: First image]

it should be "the file name is test.html"

[image: Second image]

I checked the server software version via `phpinfo()` it say this "Apache Phusion_Passenger/4.0.10 mod_bwlimited/1.4 mod_fcgid/2.3.9". now what ?

I don't even know that it is. Please tell me what server my web host is using and how can I run PHP codes in a HTML file?

Comment: www.cclasses.in/test.html      you can go n see it...

Comment: Your `html` code? `phpinfo()` showed that the `PHP` module was running. By default `*.html` and `*.php` will be interpreted by the `PHP` engine.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$url=basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
?>

<p>the file name is <?php echo $url; ?></p>
</body>
</html>

Comment: phpinfo() is running and .php files are also. but .html n .htm file are not exciting php in it.

Comment: Prior to or during editing of questions, you will receive a JavaScript-based warning if your edit would overwrite someone else's edit. When this happens, please copy your changes to clipboard, cancel the edit, refresh your page, and selectively merge the changes back in - otherwise you'll rollback edits that have improved your question.

Comment: echo is not what you want there.

Comment: You can't execute php in an html. It has to be html in php.

Comment: Not to be pedantic but the title of your question doesn't make sense with what you asked. It seems to me that you are trying to echo the name of a file and I'm guessing that you are echoing the contents of the file as a string instead.  Is that right? WHat has that got to do with executing a file with html as an extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try one of the following (probably, add to your `.htaccess`):

```
RemoveHandler .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

Or

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.html$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: forget it! i am in on another problem now.. please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30034333/in-how-many-ways-can-i-get-value-from-a-html-select-tag-without-submitting-the-f

Comment: @Meeshal you can also try RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1.php [L] in .htacess file

Answer (score 0):

Please rename the file from `test.html` to `test.php` and browse the file.It will work.

Comment: i can do that, i know but i need to execute php in html.