# In how many ways can i get value from a html select tag WITHOUT submitting the form? And what are ways that real websites use for security purposes?

Tags: php, html, forms

i am learning `php` along with `mysql` and so developing a e-comm site it is very exiting when i get hindered by some error but this time it just a `html` thing that has stopped my constuction.

so, i have to populate 2 `<select>` tags in a addProduct form for `Category` and `sub-category` but i need to work on `onChnage` event for `category` select list, as to populate the `sub-category` select list on basis of the user selection in `category` select list. i have searched a lot and some how i can do it but i want to know what are the possible ways and what is the safest way? also can i build a php function to do this if yes how to get the element value **without** submitting the form since it will submit all the form data that will empty all other fields.
thank you!

Comment: You probably want to research ajax/javascript http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: Welcome, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to have answers better than the question.

Comment: does all other website uses it 'ajax'?? can i do it just using PHP?? @STLMikey

Comment: @meeshal onChange events are handled by javascript, PHP is finished processing before the user sees the loaded webpage

Comment: i get it now! the only way i can do it by java-script, ajax and j query. thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge. @STLMikey

Comment: please answer this question so i can mark it answered..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onChange events are handled by javascript, PHP is finished processing before the user sees the loaded webpage.

To do what you are asking, you will want to utilize [javascript/AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) to update the page "on the fly"